# How to return null values using SQL Left Join

Tags: mysql, left-join

Please look at this SQL Fiddle for the tables and what query I have tried:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c7b2/1)

So basically, I have two tables namely **tbl_curriculum** and **tbl_enrolled_subjects**.

**tbl_curriculum** contains all the subjects (subject_id) a student should take based on his course (course_id).
**tbl_enrolled_subjects** contains all the subjects the student has taken/enrolled based on **tbl_curriculum**.

I want to check which subjects the student has taken and which is not, the query should return something like this:

```
Subject_id|Grade|Status
23        | 2   |Passed
24        | 2   |Passed
31        | 2   |Passed
50        | 2   |Passed
83        | 1   |Passed
27        |NULL |NULL 
28        |NULL |NULL 
29        |NULL |NULL
```

.
.
.
And So On.

Subject_ID with Grade and Status mean the student has already taken the subject. On the otherhand, NULL values indicates the the student has not taken those subjects yet.
I used this query:

```
SELECT a.subject_id, b.grade, b.status
FROM tbl_curriculum a
LEFT JOIN tbl_enrolled_subjects b
ON a.course_id = b.course_id  AND a.subject_id = b.subject_id
WHERE b.student_id_no='05-0531';
```

But I keep getting only the subjects the student has taken.

```
Subject_id|Grade|Status
23        | 2   |Passed
24        | 2   |Passed
31        | 2   |Passed
50        | 2   |Passed
83        | 1   |Passed
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't, the where clause need to be evaluated as true

Comment: @ajreal What should I do then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are not finding any nulls is because your where-clause is searching for rows with a student_id_no filled out. But, with the data you have the student_id_no will also be null in the case where the student has not taken the class...thus you are filtering out those.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.subject_id, b.grade, b.status, b.student_id_no
FROM tbl_curriculum a
LEFT JOIN tbl_enrolled_subjects b
ON a.course_id = b.course_id  AND a.subject_id = b.subject_id
where student_id_no is null or student_id_no = '05-0531'
order by subject_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c7b2/43

Comment: This works but when tried to my database which contains 100k+ records, it took 103 seconds, can you tell me what field should I add index with?

Comment: Since a left join implies returning all results from the left table I would first determine if just selecting all from tbl_curriculum suffers from slowness. If not, then the only other real fields we are using are student_id_no and the two fields we are joining with course_id and subject_id. I would try there. In general it is also always a good idea to look at the query execution plan. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

Answer (score 2):

Is very simple, you use `IS EMPTY`

In your entity you have defined a inverse key, then you call your entity principal where inverse Key IS EMPTY.

```
SELECT a FROM tbl_curriculum a WHERE a.enrollers IS EMPTY;
```

Then I have a field curriculum defined like `tbl_enrolled_subjects` in the `tbl_curriculum`

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="tbl_enrolled_subjects", mappedBy="id")
 */
private $enrollers;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query ::

```
SELECT a.subject_id, b.grade, b.status
FROM tbl_curriculum a
JOIN tbl_enrolled_subjects b
ON a.course_id = b.course_id  AND a.subject_id = b.subject_id
WHERE b.student_id_no='05-0531'
union
select subject_id,null,null 
from tbl_curriculum
where concat(subject_id,course_id) not in (
  select  concat(subject_id,course_id)
from tbl_enrolled_subjects
 WHERE student_id_no='05-0531')
```

Comment: This also works but when tried on my database which contains 100k+ records, it is painfully slow. Do you have any idea on what field should I add index with? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe putting the student filter into the JOIN predicate also gives the desired results. It works in the SQL Fiddle but I don't know how it affects the query plan.

```
SELECT a.subject_id, b.grade, b.status
FROM tbl_curriculum a
LEFT JOIN tbl_enrolled_subjects b
ON a.course_id = b.course_id  AND a.subject_id = b.subject_id
**AND** b.student_id_no='05-0531';
```